# Is there a way to track internet connection speed?

Tags: internet, speed

Is there a utility program for tracking internet connection speeds?

The program would test internet upload and download speeds periodically (e.g. once every hour) and record the results.

Comment: What OS ?  I'd imagine knowing this is quite fundimental to an answer - but the solution would be different for Linux, Mac or Windows, and I suspect even between Windows versions.

Comment: Windows Vista, 7 or 8.  I have all of them, so a program for any of them will be fine. The internet connection speed seems to vary a lot, so want to find out how bad that is in order to decide whether to switch to another provider.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of several others, including http://superuser.com/questions/13361/utility-to-monitor-internet-connectivity and http://superuser.com/questions/232317/monitoring-logging-a-malfunctioning-internet-connection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TestMy.Net offers a tool to automatically check you internet connection speed for multiple attempts. It does not run infinitely, but it should give you a good idea whether your connection speed is too slow for what you pay for.

Here's the link: http://testmy.net/auto

Make sure you don't use your connection though, otherwise your results will be skewed, best leave it running while you are at work, kids at school, etc.